# Two digit numbers instead of dots in Slick slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I want to use numbers instead of dots in my slider.
To do this, I'm using the following code:

```
$('slider').slick({
    dots: true,
    appendDots: $('slider-dots'),
    customPaging : function(slider, i) {
        var thumb = $(slider.$slides[i]).data();
        return '<a>'+(i+1)+'</a>';
    },
    arrows: false,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
}
```

Is there any way to change the numbers from single digits to two digits.
For example: 01 02 03

Comment: Use padStart: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart `(i+1).toString().padStart(2, '0')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method you are looking for is [padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart). This will add padding of some string to the beginning of another string.

```
(0).toString().padStart(2, '0')   // Result: '00'
(1).toString().padStart(2, '0')   // Result: '01'
'5'.padStart(2, '0')              // Result: '05'
(10).toString().padStart(2, '0')  // Result: '10'
'100'.padStart(2, '0')            // Result: '100'
```

So, in your case you would use this:

```
(i+1).toString().padStart(2, '0')
```

You will need to use `toString()` in order to use `padStart()` on numbers, unless the number is a stringified number.